# How to model a one-to-many relationship in JPA when the “parent” table has a composite PK?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, entity

A little bit new in JPA so stacked in Entity definition for this model.

[image]

Agents defined as follow

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "agents")
public class Agent {

    @Id
    @Column (name = "agent_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, columnDefinition = "serial")
    @Generated (GenerationTime.INSERT)
    private Integer id;

    @Column (name = "agent_name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column (name = "agent_referer_key", nullable = false)
    @Generated (GenerationTime.INSERT)
    private String referer_key;
}
```

1. How to describe partnership table if agent_id and company_id is composite primary key?
2. How to map partnership inside comp_general if company may have several partnerships?

Answer (score 0):

If a parent table contains composite key then you have to add a primary key (Auto-increment) and make the composite key as unique+notnull, so that you can refer the primary key alone where ever you want it could be your child table or any other dependencies as well. And also it will reduce your burden and reduction of replication of composite keys across the stuffs.